# D3d point group matrices

Tags: spectroscopy, symmetry, group-theory

I am trying to construct all the matrices for the point group D3d operations.   I find that the matrices of E, i, S6, inverse of S6, C3, and inverse of C3 are easy,  but I do not know how to construct the matrices of the three C2s and the three dihedral reflections.   When I construct these matrices,  they do not look like those of usual reflections or rotations.   I cannot find any resources about finding these more complicated matrices.   Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of the usual setup for the coordination system would be that $x$ axis coincident with a two-fold axis. If we use this setup, we can easily write out the matrix for rotation around this 2-fold axis:
$$\begin{bmatrix}
1&0&0\\
0&-1&0\\
0&0&-1
\end{bmatrix}.$$

Then you can combine this with the transform matrix of the 3-fold axis to get the transform matrices of the other two 2-fold axes. That's just matrix multiplication.

In this setup, $yz$ is one of the reflection plane and the corresponding matrix is
$$\begin{bmatrix}
-1&0&0\\
0&1&0\\
0&0&1
\end{bmatrix}.$$

Note that this is just the combination of the previous matrix with inversion. You can apply the 3-fold axis rotation to it (once again, matrix multiplication) to obtain the matrix with regard to other two reflection planes.